# Concurrency Issues with Domain Events

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, servicebus

I have a number of domain events that can be dispatched in our enterprise system. For example if someone creates or removes an address.

Should i be passing the entire entity as part of the event or should i just pass the ID. The messages are sent via service bus and consumed in parallel.

If i just send the ID then the entity may not be available on the consumer side, if a delete happening in the meanwhile. I can always just use an active flag and set that to false but what about if the entity was updated meanwhile and it changed something important.

How would i go about handling these cases?

Comment: Are you using eventstore?

Answer (score 2):

This I believe to be a common dilemma on a service bus, and I believe there is no one perfect solution. I'm assuming the scope here is JUST the Events raised when important domain objects change states (i.e. not Transactional Commands, nor Read / Data Services)

The decision on sending just Event metadata, versus sending a full Reference Message (e.g. a new Customer Aggregate Root) probably has wider implications than just on concurrency / versioning issues relating to latency, e.g. some pros and cons of either approach:

The minimal `Event` metadata:

- Has a much smaller payload (especially useful if you audit all messages on the bus)
- Fits nicely into standard envelopes
- Is reasonably secure if a delivered to an unauthorised bus endpoint (all the system gets is the knowledge that Customer XYZ has changed, not the actual details).

Whereas a full "aggregate" root `Message` reference update

- Can be overkill if most subscribers aren't interested in the full payload.
- Potential security concerns - not all subscribers on the bus may be entitled to the full payload
- But is great for replenishing CQRS readstore caches, as endpoints don't need to go back to the source of truth to fetch data once they know their data is out of date - the data has already been provided.

So I guess the final decision will go with what you primarily intend doing with your EDA Events (Keeping CQRS caches updated vs Triggering BPM Workflows vs Monitoring CEP Rules etc). You might decide to go with a hybrid e.g. broadcast Event Data widely, but then route full Messages to only trusted endpoints (The event meta data can likely be projected from the full payload, so the Originating / Source of Truth system can just send one message payload to the bus after each state change).

To answer your data consistency question, I believe you will need to accept that the data will only be Eventually Consistent, and that latencies will cause temporary inconsistencies across the enterprise. I believe the best pattern here is to add a hash or timestamp to each Message obtained from the originating Source of Truth, which needs to be added to any Commands which have used this version of the data as an assumption.

Then, when the command handling system processes the command, it can then check this hash against the current 'true' version (based on the actual line of business system database, NOT against a readstore Cache), and will need to fail the command if the hash / timestamps do not match up - i.e. the optimistic concurrency pattern.

Comment: One additional point would be that the EDA eventing is done in response to a Command on a LOB system. The Commands typically require an Ack/Nack style confirmation, albeit targetted at the Command originator (i.e. not broadcast), so there is overlap here, as well.